# stop showing hover on event when data not available & high some of the given date FULL Calender

Tags: jquery, calendar

hi friends i want to **stop tooltip (hidden)when title data not available** in json to display and wannna display some manually given date with **different color in the month like current date** in full calender.
this is my code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: 'calender_json.php?property_id='+propid,
            eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
                var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevetn"> '+ calEvent.customername +
                '<br/>'+ calEvent.title + 
                '<br/>'+ calEvent.test2 + 
                '<br/>'+ calEvent.test1 +
                '<br/></div>';
                $("body").append(tooltip);
                $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
                    $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                    $('.tooltipevetn').fadeIn('500');
                    $('.tooltipevetn').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
                }).mousemove(function(e){
                        $('.tooltipevetn').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                        $('.tooltipevetn').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
                });
            },
            eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent){
                $(this).css('z-index', 8);
                $('.tooltipevetn').remove();
            },      
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + 'days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
            }                       
        });
    });
```

can any one help me as i m running out of time , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dynamicTitle="")
  $('#selectorId').removeAttr("title");
```

Like this you can remove title of element.

Comment: i doo want my tool tip to display idf title not available